How to set/force EXE stack size with 1988 Turbo C 2.0 for a reverse engineering project
i try to reconstruct a Turbo C 2.0 DOS small-memory-model executable C source exact-as-possible from disassembly (its an DOS reverse-engineering project and im using IDA Pro disassembling and UASM for re-assembling and TC 2.x for the C source reconstruction)
for my normal >20years day to day development im using Windows/Linux, MSVC, gcc, clang, and all the nice new stuff and im fully aware of how exe gets built, compiler/linker works, how stack works, etc. - not a newbie :)
my start is to find out the exact Compiler for the reconstruction and build-settings that were used
according to IDA Pro and the string "Turbo-C - Copyright (c) 1988 Borland Intl." in the exe it seems to be built with Turbo 2.0 or 2.01 from 1988 (not TC 1.5 because that would say 1987) - the only difference is that the example exe i produce with TC 2.0/2.01 contains an additional Null pointer assignment string but startup-code seems to be more or less equal
now i try to force the stack size of the resulting exe but can't get it to work - there is always an default sized 0x80 size stack segment in the resulting exe
according to: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/msdos-programmer-faq/part2/section-6.html
i could use _stklen in code or STACKSIZE from a DEF file to force a size
but _stklen seem to do nothing and i don't know the syntax for the DEF file or how to let TC use the DEF file
i've found some docs about _stklen but that sounds more like a read-only value and nothing about using DEF files with TC
anyone with vague remembering how that worked exactly in the old times :)
my test.c
extern unsigned _stklen = 54321U;

int x = 10;

int main()
{
  int y;
  y = 10;
  return y;
}

build:
tcc -ms -M test.c

test.map
 Start  Stop   Length Name               Class

 00000H 00559H 0055AH _TEXT              CODE
 00560H 00701H 001A2H _DATA              DATA
 00702H 00705H 00004H _EMUSEG            DATA
 00706H 00707H 00002H _CRTSEG            DATA
 00708H 00708H 00000H _CVTSEG            DATA
 00708H 00708H 00000H _SCNSEG            DATA
 00708H 0074DH 00046H _BSS               BSS
 0074EH 0074EH 00000H _BSSEND            STACK
 00750H 007CFH 00080H _STACK             STACK <== Stacksize is always 0x80


Several people with extremely good recollection of the old times are active on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Crossposted there as https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/30986/how-to-set-force-exe-stack-size-with-1988-turbo-c-2-0-for-a-reverse-engineering
